# Multiple string and number range filters - google visualization

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, spreadsheet

I wish to include multiple string and number range filters in my database. It is only letting put one of each at the moment though and I can't figure out why.

Below is the current code I am using.

HTML:

```
<div id="dashboard">
    <div id="string_filter_div"></div>
    <div id="position"></div>
    <div id="numnber_range_filter_div"></div>
    <div id="height"></div>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Nationality');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Height');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Age');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Foot');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Position');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Overall Rating');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Attack');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Defense');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Header Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dribble Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Short Pass Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Short Pass Speed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Long Pass Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Long Pass Speed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Shot Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Place Kicking');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Swerve');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Ball Control');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weak Foot Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weak Foot Usage');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Goal Keeping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Responsiveness');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Explosive Power');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dribble Speed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Top Speed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Body Balance');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Stamina');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Kicking Power');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Jump');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Injury');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Attack 2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Defence 2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Form');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Tenacity');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Teamwork');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Owners');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Price');
    data.addRows([
        ['MESSI','FC BARCELONA','ARGENTINA',169,67,25,'Left foot','SS',98,99,38,74,98,84,82,81,81,99,85,85,93,6,4,50,84,97,98,82,83,76,80,74,2,3,2,6,76,83,904,55704866],
['INIESTA','FC BARCELONA','SPAIN',170,65,28,'Right foot','CMF',97,90,62,64,97,94,91,86,74,83,72,82,98,8,6,50,78,87,87,78,75,88,77,63,2,3,2,6,77,96,751,49828981],
['XAVI','FC BARCELONA','SPAIN',170,68,32,'Right foot','CMF',97,86,68,70,90,98,95,90,84,73,79,82,95,5,4,50,78,83,76,74,74,90,78,73,3,3,3,8,80,98,458,42893249],
['RONALDO','REAL MADRID','PORTUGAL',187,80,27,'Right foot','SS',97,99,30,95,97,83,83,87,92,92,93,85,90,7,5,50,85,87,97,87,90,78,96,89,2,3,1,5,74,72,2122,60822237],
['THIAGO SILVA','PARIS SAINT-GERMAIN','BRAZIL',183,79,28,'Right foot','CB',96,62,95,81,77,81,81,83,84,65,75,66,78,5,5,50,93,77,79,86,87,83,84,92,3,2,3,7,83,78,1203,52174484],
['AL HABSI','LANCASHIRE ATHLETIC','OMAN',194,79,30,'Right foot','GK',84,30,83,55,54,54,56,58,66,45,45,45,53,4,3,82,95,70,55,67,84,63,79,87,3,2,2,6,79,68,71,9326020]
    ]);

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.querySelector('#dashboard'));

    var stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'StringFilter',
        containerId: 'string_filter_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0
        }
    });

    var stringFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'StringFilter',
        containerId: 'position',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 7
        }
    });

    var numberRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'numnber_range_filter_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 5,
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 100,
            ui: {
                label: 'Overall Rating'
            }
        }
    });

    var numberRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'height',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 3,
            minValue: 160,
            maxValue: 210,
            ui: {
                label: 'Height'
            }
        }
    });

    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'Table',
        containerId: 'table_div',
        options: {
            showRowNumber: true
        }
    });

    dashboard.bind([stringFilter, numberRangeFilter], [table]);
    dashboard.draw(data);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['controls'], callback: drawTable});
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this code or know why? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given all controls of the same type the same variable name, so earlier controls are getting overwritten by later ones.  Use different variable names for the controls to fix this:

```
function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Nationality');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Height');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Age');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Foot');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Position');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Overall Rating');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Attack');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Defense');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Header Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dribble Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Short Pass Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Short Pass Speed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Long Pass Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Long Pass Speed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Shot Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Place Kicking');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Swerve');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Ball Control');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weak Foot Accuracy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weak Foot Usage');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Goal Keeping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Responsiveness');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Explosive Power');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dribble Speed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Top Speed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Body Balance');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Stamina');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Kicking Power');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Jump');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Injury');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Attack 2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Defence 2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Form');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Tenacity');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Teamwork');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Owners');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Price');
    data.addRows([
        ['MESSI','FC BARCELONA','ARGENTINA',169,67,25,'Left foot','SS',98,99,38,74,98,84,82,81,81,99,85,85,93,6,4,50,84,97,98,82,83,76,80,74,2,3,2,6,76,83,904,55704866],
        ['INIESTA','FC BARCELONA','SPAIN',170,65,28,'Right foot','CMF',97,90,62,64,97,94,91,86,74,83,72,82,98,8,6,50,78,87,87,78,75,88,77,63,2,3,2,6,77,96,751,49828981],
        ['XAVI','FC BARCELONA','SPAIN',170,68,32,'Right foot','CMF',97,86,68,70,90,98,95,90,84,73,79,82,95,5,4,50,78,83,76,74,74,90,78,73,3,3,3,8,80,98,458,42893249],
        ['RONALDO','REAL MADRID','PORTUGAL',187,80,27,'Right foot','SS',97,99,30,95,97,83,83,87,92,92,93,85,90,7,5,50,85,87,97,87,90,78,96,89,2,3,1,5,74,72,2122,60822237],
        ['THIAGO SILVA','PARIS SAINT-GERMAIN','BRAZIL',183,79,28,'Right foot','CB',96,62,95,81,77,81,81,83,84,65,75,66,78,5,5,50,93,77,79,86,87,83,84,92,3,2,3,7,83,78,1203,52174484],
        ['AL HABSI','LANCASHIRE ATHLETIC','OMAN',194,79,30,'Right foot','GK',84,30,83,55,54,54,56,58,66,45,45,45,53,4,3,82,95,70,55,67,84,63,79,87,3,2,2,6,79,68,71,9326020]
    ]);

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.querySelector('#dashboard'));

    var stringFilter1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'StringFilter',
        containerId: 'string_filter_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0
        }
    });

    var stringFilter2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'StringFilter',
        containerId: 'position',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 7
        }
    });

    var numberRangeFilter1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'numnber_range_filter_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 5,
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 100,
            ui: {
                label: 'Overall Rating'
            }
        }
    });

    var numberRangeFilter2 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'height',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 3,
            minValue: 160,
            maxValue: 210,
            ui: {
                label: 'Height'
            }
        }
    });

    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'Table',
        containerId: 'table_div',
        options: {
            showRowNumber: true
        }
    });

    dashboard.bind([stringFilter1, stringFilter2, numberRangeFilter1, numberRangeFilter2], [table]);
    dashboard.draw(data);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['controls'], callback: drawTable});
```